# If $X_n\overset{d}{\to}X$ and $|X_n-Y_n|\overset{d}{\to}0$, is it true to say that $Y_n\overset{d}{\to}X$?

Tags: probability-theory

I have to do a proof that would require me to prove this, but I'm not sure how to do it. Triangle inequality?

Comment: What is your setup? This question is not clear at all.

Comment: Prove what?  [The title is not the first sentence of your question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144).

Comment: Does "$\overset{d}{\to}$"mean convergence in distribution?

Comment: I think the notations are highly standard and the user is a new contributor. So let us be gentle.

Comment: Sorry $\overset{d}{\to}$ meant convergence in distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: $|X_n-Y_n| \to 0$ in distribution implies $|X_n-Y_n| \to 0$ in probability. Now $P\{Y_n \leq x\} \leq P\{X_n \leq x+\epsilon\} +P\{|X_n-Y_n| >\epsilon\}$. From this you get $\lim \sup P\{Y_n \leq x\} \leq P\{X\leq x+\epsilon\}$. Let $\epsilon \to 0$. Use a similar inequality for $\lim \inf$.